# Detect if mobile device screen is locked using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an web app which detects if the screen is in portrait mode and messages the user that they need to flip their phone to landscape. This works great until a user who has their device orientation locked at the OS level attempts to flip the phone.

Is there a way to detect if the orientation is locked from Javascript so that I can display a message to the user that they must unlock it? I know the screen API allows you to lock and unlock the browsers orientation but that is handled at a different level than the OS.

Comment: No this is not possible. Perhaps just a note in the message telling them to flip their screen you can mention remembering to unlock it if it is locked.

Comment: You could potentially detect how the device is physically rotated (using an accelerometer API) and compare that with the expected display ratio.

Comment: If the screen orientation is locked at the device level, would using Screen.unlockOrientation() still allow the browser window to rotate?